# Restore semi-formatted hdd

Tags: hard-drive, partitioning, restore

I have problems with my HDD. I tried to reinstall OS but My Windows 7 installer alerted  something like "cannot write on disk without driver" while it was deleting existing partitions. Since that my Ubuntu live hangs on load screen (several "running" dots, not matter if I choose "Try", "Install" or "Check disk"), Windows installer errors kind of "disk is damaged or badly connected, try to check your cables". Usual boot from hard drive gives "no such partition".

How do I restore HDD's operability? Losing all the information is ok.

Comment: Sounds to me like some other hardware problem... run a memtest?

Comment: @Josh But it appeared only when I was deleting partitions... Ok, I am running Memtest86 atm

Comment: If it hangs when you choose "Try" on an Ubuntu LiveCD, then it might be a problem with hardware other than the hard drive as the hard drive shouldn't be used to boot off the LiveCD. That was what made me suspect some other hardware issue. I could be wrong however!

Comment: It hangs in about 30 seconds of loading after choosing "Try". So I guess it could hang due to HDD errors while it tries to mount drive. Noteworthy, Memtest from the Ubuntu CD runs normally.

Comment: Are you booting Ubuntu from a USB pen? Is it the latest version? Can you boot into any operating system at the moment?

Comment: No, I burned image of Ubuntu 12.04 on DVD-RW. It is not the latest version, but the most stable as I know. I cannot boot from HDD due to "no such partition" eroor, it is even impossible to choose OS to load (I have two systems installed and OS loader appears every time but today)

Comment: My advice would be to try the latest version 13.04, Your hardware may be better supported. They are all stable releases, 12.04 just is just supported for longer. I take it you are using another machine? It'll be quicker to create a live version on a USB pen. You can then run some diagnostics on the HDD.

Comment: @archery1234 And Memtest gives no errors after 2 passes (runnig for one hour atm)

Comment: Is the BIOS detecting the HDD?

Comment: @archery1234 Yes, I have two machines. Ok, I will create USB with 13.04. And is it possible to format disk with another software and what is the best? It seems to be easier than with USB with live OS

Comment: @archery1234 It does. I see my HDD model on the screen with detected hardware and in boot select form (if F8 pressed)

Comment: Whichever OS you choose will partition and format the drive. It sounds like Windows 7 is no go given the installer fails. You really need to find out what is wrong with the hardware/HDD. What model is the laptop?

Comment: @archery1234 Problem is with desktop PC not with laptop. Did you mean HDD model? It is Hitachi HDT721010SLA360

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/9889/discussion-between-archery1234-and-jay-foreman)